# Text inside a div should always be aligned to middle

Tags: css

I've tried something, but vertical align doesn't work.

HTML:

```
<div class="browseBuildsArea-pro">
    <img class="champion" src="http://wiki.guildwars.com/images/d/d3/60px-Ranger-tango-icon-200.png">
    <div class="build-poster">
        <span class="middle-text">
            aaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
            bbbbbbbbbbbb<br>
            ccccccccccccc<br>
            dddddddddddd<br>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.browseBuildsArea-pro {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 790px;
    height: 90px;
    background-image:url('http://revistaverzus.com/online/background.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
div.browseBuildsArea-pro img.champion {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height: 72px;
    margin-left: 14px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    border-radius: 9px;
    -moz-border-radius: 9px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 9px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 9px;
}
div.browseBuildsArea-pro div.build-poster {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
span.middle-text {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sCWfS/1/

How can I make the text align middle regardless of the length of the content?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following CSS:

```
div {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this? http://jsfiddle.net/sCWfS/2/

Instead of span use a DIV with margin: 0 auto?

```
div.middle-text {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The vertical-align css attribute does not work for divs.
Look at this answer :
[Vertical alignment of elements in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `display: table` on the parent and `display: table-cell` on the child for vertical-align to work.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/sCWfS/3/

Comment: Please inspect the CSS in your code and see what's going on there. I can't do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
div.browseBuildsArea-pro div.build-poster {
display: block;
 position: relative;
    text-align: center;}
```